# Use ZF2 FlashMessenger as standalone component

Tags: php, zend-framework2, flash-message, flashmessenger

I working on old PHP app that is written in vanilla PHP. 
There is no any kind of MVC, but the good thing is that I can use composer.

I want to use **ZF2 FlashMessenger**. As I know FlashMessenger is only helper, part of zend-mvc and zend-view. But the question is can I use it withouth ZF2 MVC as a standalone component and how?

For eg. there is such a thing in Symfony FW - [The HttpFoundation Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html). Where you can have flash messanger in several lines of code

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set flash messages
$session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile updated');

// retrieve messages - later in layout
foreach ($session->getFlashBag()->get('notice', array()) as $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-notice">'.$message.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way wihout using at least [ZendFrameworkSkeleton](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication), since any other Single-Application (e.g. ZF-Tool) is based on it.
You can setup a Messenger-Apllication with that in a seperate directory and call it by url where you need it.